# Change PHP namespaces in forked projects? And how to open a pull request without PHP namespaces?

Tags: php, git, namespaces, pull-request, git-fork

**Question 1:** If I fork a PHP project on Github: is it good practise to **change the vendor name** in the PHP classes of the forked project? Or is it even necessary in order to avoid namespace clashes?

Example of namespace change:

```php
<?php
// namespace in PHP class in original repository
namespace originalVendor\projectName

class xyz
{
}
```

```php
<?php
// namespace in PHP class in forked repository
namespace me\projectName

class xyz
{
}
```

**Question 2:** And if I do change the PHP namespace: how can I **open a pull request** to the original repository for some added functionality **without including the change of the PHP namespace?** Even if I worked in a dedicated branch for the added functionality, I will have the new namespace in all my branches at a certain point.

Answer (score 0):

1. No, you don’t need to change vendor namespaces. Their purpose exactly to avoid clashes. Say, you have your own MyRepo\Math class, and vendor library defines BigInteger\Math, why would you want to change it? Not only it’s not a good practice, it’s not a practice at all.
2. There is no way to do that without changing namespace back to original. If you preserve your change and open up a PR, chances it will be refused is like 99.999%

**UPDATE**. As per the comment you are saying that you've made some changes to the original repo and added changes which are specific to your domain. It would help a lot if I'd be able to review those changes to give a more fine-grained advice, but in general, changes that are specific to your domain should go into your own namespace and be sort of a side-car to the original code in vendor library. Basically, you are leveraging an open source library to do your own thing, right?

Let me make up a synthetic example to illustrate what I mean by that...

Suppose your task is to log data over HTTP into your private logging server. You could use something like [`monolog`](https://packagist.org/packages/monolog/monolog) for logging, but, obviously, it lacks an ability to push logs into your `http://my-logging-server.dev`. You could clone `monolog` and add that handler into the monolog's core, but never original maintainers of monolog will accept those changes. What you wanna do instead is to write a monolog plugin in your own namespace for pushing logs into your logging server. There is an extension mechanism in monolog to do that. Basically, all you need to do is to implement monolog's `Handler` interface:

```
namespace MyNamespace;

class MyHTTPServerHandler extends \Monolog\Handler
{
    public function handle(array $record): bool
    {
        $ch = curl_init('http://my-logging-server.dev');
        curl_setopt_array($ch, [
            CURLOPT_POST => true,
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $record,
        ]);
        return curl_exec($ch);
    }
}

$logger = new \Monolog\Logger('my-logger', new MyNamespace\MyHTTPServerHandler());
```

And there you have it, you've just **extended** monolog with your own handler. Please note, I've put up this example in like 5 minutes and most probably `MyHTTPServerHandler` doesn't implement monolog's `Handler` interface properly, so the above code will not actually work... this is just a synthetic example for illustration, not for real use!

If there is no extension mechanism available, you can still use some other programming patterns to make use of external libraries in your own code. You can use `Facade`, `Adapter`, `Proxy`, `Decorator`, etc.

If, for instance, you were to add such a handler to monolog that is everyone else could benefit from, you'd be very welcome to make a PR to monolog core. Let's say `monolog` lacks an ability to use [`graylog`](https://www.graylog.org/), then yes, go ahead and make a PR to monolog without changing monolog's namespace! Because now the change is not specific to your domain, but can have a broader use as `graylog` itself is available for everyone.

Comment: Thank you! I was thinking about adding changes that I would open a pull request for to the original repository and other changes that were very specific to my use case. That’s why the question. But I guess now that even then it makes sense to not change the namespace.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Nemoden! I believe I get the point and what you describe above is in general what I meant. My usecase is as follows (and still mostly in the future): I forked a TYPO3 extension on Github that I want to use for a website project. I want to make some changes that I believe every user of the original extension would profit from. For these I would create a PR. Other changes are very specific to my website, thus of no use to other users. These will just be in “my version” of the extension.